# Is the child that is not adopted your 'blood child'?

Tags: word-request

> We have two kids -- one is adopted and the other is not. He's our *blood child*.

Is it correct to say so? For real parents we say birth parents. For real children of your own, we say what?

Comment: "blood relative" is a related term in English

Comment: Incidentally, there is a term with different implications -- "blood brother" (and by extension "blood sister"), which can mean a genetically-related brother or sister, or more commonly for this particular term, someone with whom one has sworn loyalty, sometimes via a ceremony involving their blood.

Comment: Summing up all those answers: _blood child_ is wrong. Just google it and you will see! _Bioligical child_ is the usual term.

Comment: Another point here:  It's possible to have a child that is neither adopted nor what you are calling a blood child (But what an American at least would call a biological child.)  What about a child conceived with donor eggs and/or sperm?  Not adopted but not genetically related to at least one parent, either.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel very interesting question. i think i've heard something like a **test tube baby** but im not sure. im gona find out.

Comment: @Yuri "Test tube baby" covers any situation where the fertilization occurred outside the woman, regardless of genetics.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yuri, I would say my *biological* child and my *adopted* or *chosen* child, but only if it was important to make that distinction. Normally, none of us should care. They are both/all your children and I would assumed equally wanted and loved.

*Natural* works but might lead to your other child to beg the question, "Am I *un*natural?" *Blood* child might possibly be used in another place, but not in North America by English-speakers.

Sometimes people want information. That's fine, but we are under no obligation to assuage their curiosity. If the doctor needs to know, or a child is having a problem that makes telling the school the situation, then 'step-child' or adopted child is still the way to discuss or label them.

A stepchild is a child from your spouse's former union whom you have not adopted. If you adopt them, they are your child and all the adoptive words would apply

Comment: +1 thank you, very informative. now i know how to say that in proper English and what people think if I say that.

Comment: is "stepchild" really appropriate for one's own adopted child? That doesn't seem correct to me. Stepchild is the child of one's spouse by a previous union.

Comment: Definitely "biological" child, but only if it's really relevant.

Comment: @ziggurism I answered where you left the same comment below. I will edit my answer for clarity.

Comment: @WillowRex your third paragraph still appears to say that ones own adopted child is properly referred to as a "stepchild". You should either edit that paragraph to make it clear what children you're referring to, or remove the term.

Comment: good point, .I will edit.

Comment: To be honest, if discussing it academically, one might say "my natural (or biological) child" and "my adopted/step-child", but in everyday speech, people wouldn't tend to make a distinction with the natural child - they would simply say "my child". So I would have a son and a step-son, or a daughter and an adopted daughter, to distinguish *between* them, but I woudn't generally prefix unless there was something out of the ordinary to begin with.

Comment: I advise against the use of "natural" child, especially for ESL users. It used to be a term for a child born out of wedlock back when that was a big no-no. Nowadays, it is a somewhat archaic use, but 1) it can still be misunderstood, and 2) even when not misunderstood, it can carry the unpleasant association of calling your child a bastard.

Comment: No one would say "blood child". Period.

Answer (score 8):

"Child by blood" might be correct ("blood child" sounds much more sinister, like something out of a horror movie).  However it's not a common expression, and in some contexts it might be weird, or at least impolite.

"Natural" child is a better expression.  See for example this article [Do parents favor natural children over adopted ones?](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-human-beast/200906/do-parents-favor-natural-children-over-adopted-ones)

In families that might be made of children from different parents (like the [*Brady Bunch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brady_Bunch), you can distinguish your "children by blood" from your "children by marriage", although again this might seem weird to some people. "Stepchildren" is the *proper* term; however due to negative associations (like [*Cinderella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella)'s evil stepmother) some people don't like the whole "step-" prefix and prefer to say something like, "She's my *wife's* daughter," which automatically implies that she is not your own *natural* daughter.

Comment: uhum, so let's say your child is missing. you go to a police station and the guy asks you if the missing child is an adopted one or not (maybe for possible future DNA test or something). You'd say, _"he's our child by blood."_ Is it OK? Or _"he's our natural child"_ which one you'd go with or is more common?

Comment: In the US the police wouldn't ask that question unless it was absolutely necessary to perform a DNA test for other reasons.  But if it came up I would say "he's my adopted child" if he wasn't directly related to me and it was important that they know the DNA wouldn't match  Otherwise I wouldn't say anything.  Although if it did get to that point I would probably hire an attorney to manage that relationship, since it sounds like trouble.

Comment: :-) yea, I really didn't give it much thought. you're right I probably need to get a lawyer to handle that. +1

Comment: is "stepchild" really appropriate for one's own adopted child? That doesn't seem correct to me. Stepchild is the child of one's spouse by a previous union.

Comment: No, not for adoption. Adoptive or chosen child is only for adoption. 'Step' is only for your not adopted  spouse's child.

Comment: @WillowRex I guess Andrew is referring to the Brady Bunch. There "stepchild" is indeed the proper term.

Comment: I would say "He's our **biological** child.". *Natural* sounds very strange, like your adopted child is "unnatural".  *By blood* is usually used in the context of "related by blood" (implying "by blood instead of marriage".)

Comment: @ziggurism yes, that's right.  I was talking about a related situation.

Answer (score 1):

Using blood child may confuse the other person, but I believe your intended meaning would be understandable. *Blood relatives* is commonly used to refer broadly to a family of biologically related individuals. [*Blood brothers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_brother) can refer, confusingly enough, to unrelated men who have sworn a blood oath, signified by literally cutting themselves and pressing the wounds together.

When the distinction matters for children, widely accepted as the sensitive way to express it is *biological child*. Contrariwise, someone who was adopted as an infant or newborn may as an adult seek out his birth mother or biological mother, with the latter sometimes shortened to biomom. I have never heard “biochild” used.

Simultaneously less sensitive or more dated ways to state it are

- *non-adopted child*
- *natural child*, *natural-born child*, or *real child* (using informal synonyms or euphemisms for biological)
- ***mine*** or ***my*** child (emphasizing the possessive to imply biology)
- *had him or her the old fashioned way*

The last refers to procreation, which makes it crude. Emphasizing the adoption or labeling biological children as “natural” or “real” others<sup>1</sup> an adopted child. As parents must remind our children — step-, adopted, and biological — even though something is true, saying it may not be polite.

Less common ways to express it are *flesh and blood*, *by blood*, *flesh and bone*, or *according to the flesh*<sup>2</sup>, as in “he is my flesh and bone” or “she is my flesh-and-blood child” to emphasize the biological connection.

---

**<sup>1</sup>** I find that usage as a verb grating, but [Merriam-Webster defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other) it as “to treat or consider (a person or a group of people) as alien to oneself or one's group (as because of different racial, sexual, or cultural characteristics).”

**<sup>2</sup>** Reflects similar usage in English translations of the Christian Bible (Genesis 2:23, Romans 9:8, Galatians 4:29).